# How could I map "/test/test" to a method of a controller, which is mapped to "/test"?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, annotations

I am confused by the behavior of Spring's `@RequestMapping` annotation. In the following code, `test()` is mapped to `"/test"` and `test_test()` is mapped to `"/test/test/test"`. What was happening here? And what should I do if I want to map `test()` to `"/test/test"`?

```
package com.mvc.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class Test {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test_test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: try with....@RequestMapping({"/test","/test/test"})

Comment: other way you can do is remove the requestmapping(after the controller annotation)

Comment: @PratapMurukutla That does not work. The log says `Mapped "{[/test || /test/test/test], ...`.

Comment: I do not know what you have tried..After i have seen your question, by curiousity i worked on this and tried to work with my answer,surprisingly my first answer in the coment worked..

Answer (score 1):

Spring does this intentionally; When the request mapping pattern value at method and type levels match, it uses only one of them. @See `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher#combine()`

One way is to suffix "/" to the RequestMapping value at method level (as below), so your you can use `"/test/test/"` as url ( **NOT** `/test/test`, ofcourse).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class Test {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Don't know why this was not documented.

So, I think the only remaining way to match `"/test/test"` url is to use URI template patterns.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class Test {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{anythinghere}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `"/{anythinghere}"` also matches `"/test/"` followed by any string, e.g. it matches `"/test/abc"`.

Comment: So there is no way to map to `"/test/test"`? Is it a bug of the spring framework?